# How to use jacksonxml as xmlDataFormat for bindingMode.auto in camel 3.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jackson-dataformat-xml

I changed my version of camel from 3.1.0 to 3.3.0 and my setting for bindingMode.auto doesn't work. These are the currently configurations:

For the rest endpoint:

```
private void getBooksRoute() {
        final RestOperation restOperation = booksoRestDefinition.getPortfolios();

        rest("/books").get()
                .outType(Book[].class)
                .produces("application/xml")
                .description("Search Books")

                .params(restOperation.getParametersDefinitions())
                .responseMessages(portfolioRestDefinition.responseMessagesDefinition())

                .route().routeId("get-books")
                .process(restOperation.getHeadersValidationDefinition())

                .bean(bookService, "searchBook(" +
                        "${header.bookNumber})")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    String acceptFormat = exchange.getIn().getHeader("Accept").toString();

                    if (acceptFormat.equalsIgnoreCase(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)) {
                        ArrayList<Book> books = (ArrayList<Book>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                        BookXMLWrapper bookXMLWrapper = new BookXMLWrapper();
                        bookXMLWrapper.setBooks(books);

                        exchange.getIn().setBody(bookXMLWrapper);
                    }
                })
                .endRest();
    }
```

For the binding configurations:

```
@Override
    public void configure() {
    
        restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .enableCORS(true)
                .skipBindingOnErrorCode(false)

                .apiContextPath("{{rest.swagger.context.path}}")
                .apiContextRouteId("{{rest.swagger.context.route_id}}")
                .contextPath("{{rest.api.context.path}}")

                .apiProperty("api.title", "{{rest.api.title}}")
                .apiProperty("api.version", "{{rest.api.version}}")
                .apiProperty("cors", "{{rest.api.cors}}")
                .apiProperty("schemes", "{{rest.api.schemes}}")
                .apiHost("{{rest.api.host}}")

                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.xml)
                .xmlDataFormat("jacksonXml")
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
                .dataFormatProperty("contentTypeHeader", "true");

        rest()
                .end();
```

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-boot-version>2.2.13.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
    <camel-spring-boot-version>3.3.0</camel-spring-boot-version>
    <commons-services-version>0.12.14</commons-services-version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.12</lombok.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-spring-boot-version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring-boot -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Request for JDK 10+ -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jacksonxml-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jpa-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-spring-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>3.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
      <version>0.38</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
      <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
      <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
      <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Auth0 JWT  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

But after camel upgraded from 3.2.0 to 3.3.0 when I try to access the endpoint I get this error:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route get-books: Route(get-books)[From[rest://get:xxxxxx@0x7256bc2], Log... because of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XML DataFormat jacksonXml not found.

    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.start(DefaultModel.java:356)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.startRoute(DefaultModel.java:330)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultModel.java:323)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultModel.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultModel.java:302)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.AbstractModelCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(AbstractModelCamelContext.java:326)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2679)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.lambda$doStart$2(AbstractCamelContext.java:2527)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(AbstractCamelContext.java:2544)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2525)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2421)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.CamelAnnotationsHandler$8.execute(CamelAnnotationsHandler.java:358)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.CamelSpringTestHelper.doToSpringCamelContexts(CamelSpringTestHelper.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.CamelAnnotationsHandler.handleCamelContextStartup(CamelAnnotationsHandler.java:353)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.CamelSpringBootExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(CamelSpringBootExecutionListener.java:90)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:108)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:151)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XML DataFormat jacksonXml not found.
    at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeCamelException(RuntimeCamelException.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:112)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XML DataFormat jacksonXml not found.
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.rest.RestBindingReifier.createRestBindingAdvice(RestBindingReifier.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:396)
    ... 67 more
```

**I wonder what am I missing to be able to use jacksonxml as xmlDataFormat.**

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

**Note**: I updated the name of the xmlDataFormat from jacksonxml to jacksonXml when I changed the version, since keeping the old name asked me to include the jaxb dependency in the class-path

I would expect to be able to use jacksonxml as xmlDataFormat since all the annotations I have in the pojos are from `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `camel-jacksonxml` module as a dependency rather than the `camel-jaxb` module as you are hinting the `jacksonXml` data format configuration.

> Note the uppercase **X** in `jacksonXml` data format name that you
> should fix as well.

Comment: Hi, actually I had it like you said. I added to the question more details to include the test I did based in your comments.

Comment: Can you please add the full route and REST DSL configurations along with the full stack trace and your project dependencies declaration.

Comment: I updated the question with the full route and binding configurations, thanks

Comment: @eepinera thanks for the update. Given your configuration everything looks like to be properly setup. This is more of a bug in Apache Camel as this should work as expected.

Comment: Hi i confirm is a camel bug...